# rgbdslam build error

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, g2o, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!
I tried installing rgbdslam, but got this error:

### {-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
rm -rf lib include bin
mkdir -p build/g2o/build
cd build/g2o/build && cmake ../ -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/sunilsulania/ros/g2o && make install
CMake Error: The source directory "/home/sunilsulania/ros/g2o/build/g2o" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.

[

I have Ubuntu 11.04 and ros-electric version on my laptop. I was successful in doing same on workstation with same Ubuntu and ros versions.
The only difference here in laptop is that I dont have root, and someone had already worked on this lappy with rgbdslam and g20 etc.
I am new to ROS, will appreciate any help!
Thanks in advance!
Sourav

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42936/rgbdslam-build-error/) by [sunilsulania9192](https://answers.ros.org/users/748/sunilsulania9192/) on ROS Answers with karma: 224 on 2012-09-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the error is only with g2o. Have you built g2o before rgbdslam? If not do,

$rosmake g2o

$rosmake rgbdslam

otherwise (if g2o is already built)

$rosmake --pre-clean rgbdslam.

---

Originally posted by [Sudhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1685/sudhan/) with karma: 171 on 2012-09-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0